# Last run code is having problems with starting the code because indented block

Tags: python

Im having problem with the last code- "intro()" its stopping me from running the code so if anyone would be able to figure out whats wrong it would be of big help

*
I believe its not working because of a typo somewhere but iam unable to locate it or fix it so i hope any of yall can spot it and help me out?

it asks me to add more detail but there isnt much more i can say :/

```
  import time
from termcolor import colored, cprint

answer_A = ["A", "a"]
answer_B = ["B", "b"]
answer_C = ["C", "c"]
yes = ["Y", "y", "yes"]
no = ["N", "n", "no"]

phone = 1
Lady_name = 0
Lady_lastname = 0


required = ("\nUse only A, B, or C\n") 

print("=========================================================")
def Intro():
  print ("\n\n You are sitting at the bar like every friday... ")
  time.sleep(2)
  print ("\n After your wife passed away, you don't really know what to do anymore")
  time.sleep(2)
  print ("\n You see a lady looking at you in the cornor of your eye.")
  time.sleep(2)
  print("""\n  A. Move over and talk to the lady .
  B. Let the lady be, she probably thinks you are weird.""")
  choice = input(">>> ")
  if choice in answer_A:
    time.sleep(1)
    option_lady()
  elif choice in answer_B: 
    print("\n You let the lady be... \n You have been sitting here a while now and the lady have been glancing over at me the whole time.")
    time.sleep(3)
    print ("\n You glance over at her wondering if she is watching you.")
    time.sleep(2)
    print ("\n You make eye contact")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("""\n  A. Go and talk to the lady.
    B. Go home for the night.""")
  choice = input(">>> ") 
  if choice in answer_A:
    option_lady()
  elif choice in answer_B:
    print("\n You go and home and the lady looks sad. \n\n You go to sleep and never wake up again...")
  
    def option_lady():
      print ("\n you walk over to the lady")

      print("""\n  A. Hey, how you doing?
      B. Hey, whats your name?""")
      choice = input(">>> ")
      if choice in answer_A:
        option_question
      elif choice in answer_B:
        Lady_name = 1
        Lady_lastname = 1
        print ("\n Hey, Whats your name? You say.")
        time.sleep(1)
        cprint ('\nTracey! My name is Tracey smith.', 'red')
        time.sleep(1)
        Lady_name = 1
        Lady_lastname = 1
        print("\nWhat are you gonna answer? ")
        print("""\n A. How are you doing?
        \nB. Can I buy you a drink?""")
        choice = input (">>> ")
        if choice in answer_A:
          print("dsa")
        elif choice in answer_B:








Intro()
'
```

Comment: Please give a proper description of the problem and post the full error traceback!

Comment: idk if i understand what u mean by that but when i hover over intro() it says " [pyflakes] expected and indented block " and when i run the code it says "indentationerror: expected an indented block"

Answer (score 0):

Your code ends in `elif choice in answer_B:`. Any statement ending in `:` *must* have a body, some code. If you explicitly don't want to put anything there, python provides `pass` exactly for that reason.:

```
   elif choice in answer_B:
     pass
```

should fix it.